# {{siteUrl}} not working on load

Tags: templating, siteurl

I am using `{{ siteUrl }}` for absolute links. It works 95% of the time. But if I press the reload button multiple times in a few seconds (overloading or something) my links look like this:

```
href="$DEFAULT_SITE_URL/css/order.css"
```

instead of

```
href="http://localhost/craft/web/css/order.css"
```

other Twig commands are working fine at the same time. What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `{{ currentSite.baseUrl }}`

I had the same issue when I started using environment variables instead of `@web` for my sites. I've found the above works for all cases.